# Recursion in the calculus of construction

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, coq, lambda-calculus, typed-lambda-calculus

How to define a recursive function in the (pure) [calculus of constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions)? I do not see any fixpoint combinator there.

Comment: A function f calling a function g is a function composition. If f is calling itself, then you have a function composition involving the same function.

Comment: No fixpoint  combinator is definable in CoC. That would allow non-termination, and there are no non-terminating CoC terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

People in the [CS stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/type-theory) might be able to provide some more insight, but here is an attempt.

Inductive data types are defined in the calculus of constructions with a [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding): the data type is the type of its fold function.  The most basic example are the natural numbers, which are defined as follows, using a Coq-like notation:

```
nat := forall (T : Type), T -> (T -> T) -> T
```

This encoding yields two things: (1) terms `zero : nat` and `succ : nat -> nat` for constructing natural numbers, and (2) an operator `nat_rec` for writing recursive functions.

```
zero : nat
zero T x f := x

succ : nat -> nat
succ n T x f := f (n T x f)

nat_rec : forall T, T -> (T -> T) -> nat -> T
nat_rec T x f n := n T x f
```

If we pose `F := nat_rec T x f` for terms `x : T` and `f : T -> T`, we see that the following equations are valid:

```
F zero = x
F (succ n) = f (F n)
```

Thus, `nat_rec` allows us to define recursive functions by specifying a return value `x` for the base case, and a function `f` to process the value of the recursive call. Note that this does not allow us to define arbitrary recursive functions on the natural numbers, but only those that perform recursive calls on the predecessor of their argument. Allowing arbitrary recursion would open the door to partial functions, which would compromise the soundness of the calculus.

This example can be generalized to other inductive data types.  For instance, we can define the type of lists of natural numbers as the type of their fold right function:

```
list_nat := forall T, T -> (nat -> T -> T) -> T
```

Comment: What about a recursive call to a strictly smaller argument (according to a well-founded relation)?

Comment: Well-founded recursion in Coq is also implemented in terms of structural recursion (on an "accessibility predicate" derived from the well-founded relation), so the same technique should apply. I'm actually not certain whether Coq's fixpoints are easily encodable that way, because the primitive property required by Coq's termination checker seems rather nontrivial: it applies not only to direct subterms (after taking off one constructor), but also those obtained transitively, even looking through nested fixpoints.

Comment: How is then the induction principle defined for Church encoded natural numbers in CiC? [This answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/30924/24156) seems to say that something else is also required, or else the type is "too big" (=contains exotic, strange elements).

Comment: @larsr you cannot define an induction principle for all elements of a Church encoded type, neither in CoC nor in CiC. Having an induction principle was one of the reasons for introducing inductive types.